# Перейти в другое приложение по нажатии на картинку

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как в андроиде реализовать переход из одного приложения в другое по нажатию соответствующей картинке в res layout?

Если точнее, мне нужно из моего приложения при нажатии на куртинку перейти в Skype.

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:src="@drawable/verticalbutton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView28"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView23"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.911"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView23"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
```

Это код фрагмента, на котором находится кнопка

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.example.myapplicationtz.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

}
```

А вот класс MainActitvity

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
//        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К layout вашего ImageView добавьте строки:

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
```

Инициализируйте Ваш imageView в коде вашего фрагмента:

```
imageView = root.findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
```

Добавьте обработчик нажатия для вашего imageView в коде вашего фрагмента

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.android"));
        }
    });
```